# Opencv_traincascade froze

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning

I have got some problems with training my cascade classifier, opencv_traincascede.It didn't work properly. Previous stage takes 12 min to complete, but at 20th stage it gives:

```
===== TRAINING 20-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   500 : 500
```

and nothing more in the next 45 minutes. I expected something like:

```
===== TRAINING 20-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   500 : 500
NEG current samples  <negNum>
```

Should I restart the training?

-numStages 30

Anyway in task manager traincascade eats 35% CPU (i5)

Comment: I had a training that took about 3 days!! I don't know what is your  problem context! If you explain more it would be better!

Comment: please post your complete cmdline

Answer (score 1):

(not an answer, still..)

- each stage takes like exponentially longer than the last one
- you *can* break it, and resume later.
  if you ctrl^c'ed it at .g. stage 17, rerun your cmdline with -numStages 16,
  this will generate a cascade.xml for the current 16 valid stages (n# 17 might be broken)
  at least you can try out your current cascade this way. later restart with -numStages 30,
  to continue the training
- while lbp or hogcascades are (slightly) less accurate, they train in *minutes* instead of days, 
  so *until* you get nice results, you should try that. (if it does not work at all, 
  haar cascades won't either)
- 30 stages sounds insane. if you don't get results with 20, 30 won't help
- [http://answers.opencv.org/questions/scope:all/sort:relevance-desc/query:cascade%20training/page:1/](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/scope%3aall/sort%3arelevance-desc/query%3acascade%20training/page:1/)

---

last but not least, we don't know, what you're training there. some kind of objects might not fit the cascade scheme at all, and might need a different treatment.